# Where to prompt for location authorization in singleton LocationManager class

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I'm creating a map app that uses geofencing. I got geolocation working instantiating a location manager "as needed" on 2 view controllers, but that's terrible practice, so I created a singleton `LocationManager` class.

When I access `currentLocation` from my `MapViewController` with this code:

```
[LocationManager sharedInstance].currentLocation;
```

I get this warning:

`Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects`

**Update: Immediate problem solved, new problem created**

In my `MapViewController.m` I had this property declared prior to creating a singleton `LocationManager` class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

I set that property to the value in the singleton with this line:

```
self.currentLocation = [LocationManager sharedInstance].currentLocation;
```

...and the warning went away.

**New problem: Where to request location authorization**

With that basic problem out of the way, I've encountered a new one:

I need this code to go somewhere in my `LocationManager` class:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

I had it in `viewWillAppear` in my `MapViewController` before `startUpdatingLocation` previously, but tweaking that to refer to the singleton `LocationManager` in `MapViewController` generates this log:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

I think I need to put the prompt for location authorization in my `LocationManager` class, but the where is tripping me up.

**`LocationManager.h`**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

+(LocationManager *)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;

- (void)startUpdatingLocation;
```

**`LocationManager.m`**

```
#import "LocationManager.h"

@implementation LocationManager

+ (LocationManager *)sharedInstance {
    static LocationManager *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^ {
        instance = [[self alloc]init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; // meters
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startUpdatingLocation {
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Location service failed with error %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Latitude %+.6f, Longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
    self.currentLocation = location;
}
```

Comment: in which class u access this method show the code also

Comment: Have you implemented a custom `currentLocation`?

Comment: Nothing "custom". I just want to grab the location from `LocationManager` and dump it in `MapViewController`.

Comment: "Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects"

You're calling the getter method (implicitly), but you're not doing anything with it (like assigning it to a CLLocation*). This warning is about that, you can just get rid of it with :

CLLocation* curLocation = [LocationManager sharedInstance].currentLocation;

Comment: That was it! I just did this to shut up the compiler. `self.currentLocation = [LocationManager sharedInstance].currentLocation;` My question is proof positive there ARE stupid questions--lots of them!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `MapViewController.m` I had this property declared prior to creating a singleton `LocationManager` class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

I set that property to the value in the singleton with this line:

```
self.currentLocation = [LocationManager sharedInstance].currentLocation;
```

...and the warning went away.

While I'm tempted to delete this post, I'm leaving it up in case someone else stumbles into the same issue following a tutorial.

**Update: Second Problem Solved:**

```
- (id)init {
        self = [super init];
    if (!self.locationManager) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; // meters
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I threw a breakpoint into the initializer in my `LocationManager` class and discovered:

```
if (!self)
```

should be:

```
if (!self.locationManager)
```

Comment: This link can help you with to save battery and avoid invalid locations : https://gist.github.com/kwylez/2421914.

Comment: I'll take a look at that later. For now, I'm just trying to get my app working and keep my head above water.